# Skype snap not starting, just blinks and it's closed

Tags: 17.10, skype, snap

Running Ubuntu 17.10.1, Skype installed from the official snap, current version 8.18.0.6, in classic mode.

When I try to start it, nothing happens. The very first time I try after a reboot, a quick blink of the screen, and then nothing. No process running, no error message, nothing.

From the command line, same result. I have tried running:

```
skype
snap run skype
```

How can I debug this? Any way to see some error message?
Nothing on syslog or dmesg.

Thanks.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue

Comment: Even reinstalling from Software center didn't solve this.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. I think that if you want to debug this issue the following link is a good place to start:

https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/snapd-not-returning-desktop-file-for-skype/4159

I have confirmed that the issue reported there still applies to version "8.18.0.6". I am not completely sure if the issue reported there is directly related with your problem but I suspect that it is. I am afraid I can not provide further clues at this point.

Comment: Thanks for that. Searching on that forum I found this: https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/cant-launch-skype-snap-relocation-error/4536/8

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Jose_O's answer I have found this conversation in the snapcraft.io forum:
https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/cant-launch-skype-snap-relocation-error/4536/8

It seems the issue is known, and they are working on it. Hopefully we'll get a fixed version of Skype soon.

In the mean time, and also from that conversation, I can run a previous version of Skype with this command:
/snap/skype/16/usr/share/skypeforlinux/skypeforlinux
which starts version 8.16.
Looking in the /snap/skype folder you should see which (if any) previous versions of Skype you have available.

UPDATE: Today Skype works, version 8.18.0.6 (23). Looks like it got updated about 12 hours ago. Awesome!

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled and reinstalled the snap version and could not get it to work. With the snap version uninstalled, I installed the deb version (use pull down on web page to select deb) from here:  [Skype](https://www.skype.com/en/get-skype/")

Next problem, I have a web cam with microphone, but Skype can't see the mic.  This all used to work on 17.10. Not sure when it broke.